# Reading multine text inside a bash script

Tags: bash, here-document

I have following `graphviz` script which I wish to convert to a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash  
graph=$(cat <<GRAPHEND
graph match { 
    node[style=filled shape=point label= ""];
    size="40.0,40.0";
    fontsize=10.0;
    overlap=false ;
    spline=true; 
    nodesep=4.0;
    "aaa" -- "aab" [penwidth=2.25 color="red" label="4" fontsize=7.0];
} GRAPHEND
)
echo $graph
#neato -Tpng $graph > graph.png
```

This trial is failing with following error

```
./high_match.dot: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
./high_match.dot: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

PS : Line no in second line may not be accurate as I have edited the file here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GRAPHEND` should be on a new line.

```
#!/bin/bash  
graph=$(cat <<GRAPHEND
graph match { 
    node[style=filled shape=point label= ""];
    size="40.0,40.0";
    fontsize=10.0;
    overlap=false ;
    spline=true; 
    nodesep=4.0;
    "aaa" -- "aab" [penwidth=2.25 color="red" label="4" fontsize=7.0];
}
GRAPHEND
)
echo $graph
```